# How to change xlim or scale of each facet in ggplot based on quantitle?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(a = as.numeric(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), 
                 b = as.numeric(c(1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 1000)),
                 c = as.numeric(c(0.07, 0.09, 6, 9, 10, 30)))

ggplot(gather(na.omit(df)), aes(x = value, y = ..density..))+
    geom_histogram(bins = 5, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
    facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(5))+
    geom_density(alpha = .2, fill = "#FF6666")
```

The output of above script as below:

[image]

As for there are outliers such as `1000`,`0.07`  in `df`, the scale x stretched, making density line invisible.

Is there a way to subset `facet` by `quantile(facet,c(0.01,0.99))`,or `xlim = quantile(facet, c(0.01,0.99))` to exclude outlier in scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trim your data inside a `sapply`.

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df1, function(x){
  qu <- quantile(x, c(0.01, 0.99))
  x[which(x > qu[1] & x < qu[2])]}))
df2
#   a  b     c
# 1 2  3  0.09
# 2 3  3  6.00
# 3 4  5  9.00
# 4 5 10 10.00
```

Or, with `data.table::between`, which is useful here for intervals.

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df1, function(x)
  x[which(x %between% quantile(x, c(0.01, 0.99)))]))
df2
#   a  b     c
# 1 2  3  0.09
# 2 3  3  6.00
# 3 4  5  9.00
# 4 5 10 10.00
```

Then just use your old code. I adapted it a little and rather use base R's `stack` here which does the same as `gather` to avoid having to load too much additional packages.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(stack(na.omit(df2)), aes(x=values, y=..density..)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=5, colour="black", fill="white") +
  facet_wrap(~ind, scales='free_x') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(5)) +
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")
```

***Result***

[image]

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), b = c(1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 
1000), c = c(0.07, 0.09, 6, 9, 10, 30)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: I agree `stack` is better than `gather`

Comment: Is there alternative to `%between%`?

Answer (score 1):

We could `filter` the `value` based on `quantile` for each `key` and then plot

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  filter(value > quantile(value, 0.01) & value < quantile(value, 0.99)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = value, y = ..density..) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(5)) +
  geom_density(alpha = .2, fill = "#FF6666")
```

[image]